# PHP troubles with special characters by reading a txt file flie_get_contents

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I have this code:

```
<?php
$s2 = file_get_contents("s2.txt");
?>
<div id="slogan">
<em>asd</em>
<strong><?php echo $s2; ?></strong>
<span>dsa</span>
</div>
```

For example if in the file(s2.txt) I have written: açs; It will display me a�s.
What can I do to write açs instead of a�s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you encode the $s2 string to UTF-8.

You can do that with the PHP function `utf8_encode(string)`

```
<?php
$s2 = file_get_contents("s2.txt");
?>
<div id="slogan">
<em>asd</em>
<strong><?php echo utf8_encode($s2); ?></strong>
<span>dsa</span>
</div>
```

This should fix it for you.

Comment: You can also encode the file_get_contents() instead, if this works out better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following snippet:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
     $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

$s2 = file_get_contents_utf8("s2.txt");
```

It encode the string to `UTF8`